# How to vary output current by maintaining constant output voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, control, solenoid-valve

I want to control a [proportional valve](https://www.bibus.ch/fileadmin/editors/countries/bagch/3_Fluidtechnik/camozzi/Downloads/englisch/Camozzi_Serie_AP_Datasheet_ENG.pdf) by keeping its voltage constant while varying its output current. Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Please list the valve and what you have tried so far

Comment: Why do you need to keep the voltage constant?

Comment: "varying its output current" A valve does not have an "output current". Do you mean "its **input** current"?

Answer (score 3):

Not unless you can change the valve's impedance as well.

From Ohm's Law we have Z = E / I, if voltage E is constant and current I changes then impedance Z must also change.

Edit: Now that you've added the spec sheet for the valve, it looks like what you really want is to drive it with a variable current source. The way a current source works is that it adjusts the voltage to keep the current at the set value. So let's take the GP7 model for instance, it's nominal resistance is listed as 193\$\Omega\$ and rated current as 125 mA. This works out to a voltage of:
$$
193\Omega \times 125mA = 24.125V
$$
So this is a 24 V valve. If you want to control it with current you would use some percentage of the maximum. Let's say you want 80% current, that's 100 mA, so the voltage across the coil will be
$$
193\Omega \times 100mA = 19.3V
$$
So you can see that if the impedance is constant, and you vary the current, the voltage will also vary. So while you do want varying current, you do not want constant voltage.

The reason to use a current source is to eliminate the effect of wire resistance. If you used a constant voltage and the wires to the valve were rather long there would be voltage drop in the wires and the valve would not get the full voltage. By using a current source the voltage will be adjusted to cancel that out. For example if you used the GP7 valve and a constant 24 V supply with wires that have 10\$\Omega\$ resistance you would have a total resistance of 203\$\Omega\$ and the voltage across the valve would be
$$
\frac{193\Omega}{203\Omega}\times 24 V = 22.8 V
$$
and it would only be getting 95% of the current it should be. A constant current supply would put out a voltage high enough to cause 125 mA to flow through the total resistance of the wires and valve coil so the current and voltage to the valve will be correct regardless of the wire resistance.